# foreach with database connection freezes with no error, forever

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, doparallel

```
library(doParallel)
library(RMySQL)

no_cores <- as.integer(system('getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN', intern = TRUE)) - 1
cluster <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterEvalQ(
  cluster, 
  mysql <- RMySQL::dbConnect(...)
  }
)

r <- foreach(i = 1:50, .verbose = TRUE) %dopar% { dbGetQuery(mysql, 'show tables;')}

no variables are automatically exported
```

There's no error, no complaint. Nothing, it just freezes. I can start and use a cluster without database connections.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When does it hang? When calling `clusterEvalQ` or the foreach loop?

I have a few suggestions:

- Use `outfile=""` when creating the cluster to get debug output;
- Load `RMySQL` when initializing the cluster;
- Return `NULL` from `clusterEvalQ` to avoid serializing connection objects;
- Make sure you call `registerDoParallel` so the tasks aren't executed locally.

Here's a test that uses these suggestions:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3, outfile="")
registerDoParallel(cl)

clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(RMySQL)
  mysql <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='root',
                     password='notmypasswd', dbname='mysql')
  NULL
})

r <-
  foreach(i=1:50, .verbose=TRUE) %dopar% {
    dbGetQuery(mysql, 'show tables;')
  }
```

This test works for me. When I run it, I see messages like:

```
no variables are automatically exported
numValues: 50, numResults: 0, stopped: TRUE
got results for task 1
numValues: 50, numResults: 1, stopped: TRUE
returning status FALSE
got results for task 2
```

If you only see:

```
no variables are automatically exported
```

and then it hangs, then the workers are presumably hanging trying to perform the query using the database connection. That sounds like a MySQL problem to me, but I'm not a MySQL expert.

Comment: Thanks Steve, it's definitely the last part. I get nothing, it just hangs so maybe it's the DB connection  that's failing. I just wish there was some output. I left it for about 20 mins and it was still there just stuck, no error messages or anything. I also neglected to add `registerDoParallel` to my example, but it's in my actual. I'll try your suggestions and let you know if any of them worked. Appreciate your attention here!

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on what you mean by "avoid serializing the connection objects"?

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen In my example, if I didn't include the `NULL` when calling `clusterEvalQ`, it would attempt to return a list of the connection objects created by the workers. Since database connections objects contain socket connections, that would result in a serialization error. I don't think that would cause any real problem, but it is disturbing.

Comment: For passerby, I followed @SteveWeston 's recommendation and added the NULL as specified, and also added doParallel to the Depends line of my package.